# JavaScript border-color/color styling not working on mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, css, colors, border

I'd like to style 'input.submit' of a form (hover effect for IE) using JS and tried the following which doesn't work unfortunately.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">

// CHANGE SUBMIT STYLE
var foo = document.getElementByClass('input.submit');
foo.onmouseover = this.style.border-color='#000000'; this.style.color='#000000';
foo.onmouseout = this.style.border-color='#888888'; this.style.color='#888888';
foo.onclick = this.style.border-color='#000000'; this.style.color='#000000';

</script>
<![endif]-->
```

How can I fix this so that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is considerably more complicated if the elements are generated by an external javascript script. You'll need to find the element first, so the by `id` and `class` approaches won't work unless they already have one - see the `type` solution below.

**Find by `id`:**

The following is preferred, you need to add an id to the input submit e.g. `<input type="submit" id="submit">` to reference it by:

```
// CHANGE SUBMIT STYLE
var foo = document.getElementById('submit');
foo.onmouseover = function() {this.style.borderColor='#000000'; this.style.color='#000000';}
foo.onmouseout = function() {this.style.borderColor='#888888'; this.style.color='#888888';}
foo.onclick = function() {this.style.borderColor='#000000'; this.style.color='#000000';}
```

but the following should also work:

**Find by `class`:**

you'll need to specify a class e.g. `<input type="submit" class="submit">` in this case.
 `getElementsByClass` doesn't look for the `type`, it looks for the `class`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getElementsByClass(node,searchClass,tag) {
  var classElements = new Array();
  var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  var elsLen = els.length;
  var pattern = new RegExp("\b"+searchClass+"\b");
  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
    if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
      classElements[j] = els[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
return classElements;
}

// CHANGE SUBMIT STYLE
var foo = getElementsByClass(document.body, 'submit', 'input')[0];
foo.onmouseover = function() {this.style.borderColor='#000000'; this.style.color='#000000';}
foo.onmouseout = function() {this.style.borderColor='#888888'; this.style.color='#888888';}
foo.onclick = function() {this.style.borderColor='#000000'; this.style.color='#000000';}

</script>
```

**Find by `type`:**

You could find by `type` if you use the following:

```
function getElementByType(node,type,tag) {
  var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  for (var x=0, x<els.length; x++) {
    if (els[x].type && els[x].type.toLowerCase() == type) {
      return els[x]
    }
  }
}
var foo = getElementByType(document.body, 'submit', 'input')
...
```

What I would do is:

```
<div id="externalElms">
    (<script> here)
</div>
```

then use `var foo = getElementByType(document.getElementById('externalElms'), 'submit', 'input')` so it doesn't have to go through every element on the page.

Comment: It's getting much clearer now. I would have added an ID for the input and then used the document.getElementById method but the input itself is created by an external JS script. So, I'll have to give the alternative solution a try. Thanks, David!

Comment: Another idea: Wouldn't it be possible to attach an ID to the input first (using JS) and then call it by document.getElementById?

Comment: @Dan: Added a faster option, but you need to find the element before setting the `id`, so it may not be worth it unless you need to access it again using `document.getElementById`

Comment: Thanks so much, David. I think I'll get this going... Bye.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
foo.onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.borderColor='#000000'; 
    this.style.color='#000000';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply! I've tried this but there's no effect at all. Could I use 'getElementByID' instead of 'getElementByClass' because I suggest that may cause the problem? It's '#HCB_comment_box input.submit' if that helps...

Comment: So, if I understand you right the problem is that there's no ID specified for the input and `document.getElementByClass('input.submit');` resp. `document.getElementByClass('submit');` won't work, right?